# How Do I Cause Renderer to Show Cue Banner When Text Reverted to Blank?

Tags: extjs, grid

I have a renderer set up on my Sencha Ext.JS 3.4 EditorGridPanel.  I allow the user to click a button, add rows and fill in various cells in those rows, and I set up a cue banner to show some useful text as soon as a blank row is added.

My cue banner solution is based on [another SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21556011/4567871), and the solution works great except for one small caveat: when someone types in text in one of the cells and later **reverts that text to blank**, whatever was there before is kept instead of becoming blank.  You can edit to your heart's content, but as soon as you try to delete all text in a cell, your changes are ignored.

I've looked through the Sencha docs on the renderer and the onblur and even the listener parameters, and I've tried trapping the onblur event, but no events seem to even fire (using Chrome developer tools breakpoints).  Is there a way to get this to work so that someone can revert the text to blank once they've typed?

**Some Relevant Code:**
 (per comment request)

```
  function renderCueBanner( value, metaData, record, rowIndex, colIndex, store ) {
     if( !value && record.phantom )
        return 'Double-click, and type';
     else
        return value;
  }

  //other code

MyCompany.ui.grid.Macros = Ext.extend(Ext.grid.EditorGridPanel, {
  title: 'Macros',

  //other code

  var config = {
     stripeRows: true,
     viewConfig: { emptyText: 'No Macros to display' },
     loadMask: true,
     store: store,
     sm: sm,
     tbar: tbar,
     colModel: new Ext.grid.ColumnModel({
        defaults: {
           menuDisabled: true
        },
        columns: [sm, {
           header: 'Macro Category',
           dataIndex: 'group',
           sortable: true,
           editor: {
              fieldLabel: 'Macro Category',
              forceSelection: false,
              typeAhead: false,
              valueField: 'name',
              xtype     : 'MyCompany.ui.autocompleter.MacroGroup'
           },
           renderer  : renderCueBanner,
           width: 150
        }, {
           header: 'To',
           dataIndex: 'to',
           editor: {
              xtype: 'textfield',
              allowBlank: false
           },
           sortable: true,
           renderer  : renderCueBanner,
           width: 400
        }],
        listeners: {
           'onblur' : {
               fn: renderCueBanner,
               handler: renderCueBanner,
               delay: 100
           }
        },
        isCellEditable: function(col, row) {
           if (!Lynx.userCan('write')) {
              Ext.Msg.alert(
                 'Access Denied',
                    'You are a read only user'
              );
              return false;
           }
           return Ext.grid.ColumnModel.prototype.isCellEditable.call(this, col, row);
        }
     }),
     //...other code...
   };
```

Comment: Could you please post your relevant code?

Comment: I added some of my code; notice the renderer properties.  Also, the "listeners" was my attempt to add an onblur listener that I could use to fix this undesired behavior; it didn't work, but I left it in there.  The renderer solution works fine without it (except for the obvious problem in my question).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is most likely caused by `allowBlank:false` in combination with the default value of [`revertInvalid:true`](http://docs-origin.sencha.com/ext/5.1/5.1.0-apidocs/#!/api/Ext.Editor-cfg-revertInvalid).

The behavior is as expected in fact: You do not allow the field to stay blank so the editor reverts to the last valid, non-blank value.

Try to add `revertInvalid:false` or remove `allowBlank:false` (preferred) and it should work.